# res.json not working and defaulting to last used res.send, even if this code isn't there any more

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have some code in express that creates a Mongoose document from the values sent in body. I'm trying to send back JSON results for both succeeding and failing (validation happens with Mongoose). But res.json() isn't working at all.

Instead of the object I'm trying to send, the result is the last value sent with res.send(), even when res.send isn't anywhere in the code any more. I only get back the text that was last used, in both cases so their is also no difference in values. As you can see I tried res.send() with "success" and "no success" and the last call was "success", so now both with succeeding and failing, it always send "success" back instead of the JSON I want.

If I change the HTTP status before calling json(), the correct status is sent, but the value is still wrong.

```
router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    const user = new User(req.body);
    user.save().then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
        console.log('success');
        // res.json({success: true});
        res.send('success');
    }).
    catch ((err) => {
        console.log('error');
        // res.json({error: 'ikke'});
        res.send('no success');
    });
});
```

**App.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
var logger = require('morgan');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/kb-skills', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, does your code actually have `= >`or `=>`? Only the latter is valid.

Comment: It's => in the correct way, I have no idea why that changed here

Comment: Are you calling this code from a frontend or just trying it with your browser? Check the endpoint with your browser's developer tools' Network tab - see what response code you're getting and whether it's a cached response. Try clearing the cache.

Comment: I'm using postman to test right now, which has a no-cache header by default, so it shouldn't be the case

Comment: Also, when I change the status to anything else the correct status is shown, but still the wrong value, so it's not a cached response

Comment: In that case, please try to make a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can try. Or at least include as much of your code before the route as you can. This is not about this route handler - it's either somewhere before it (in express) or after it (between your express server and your postman).

Comment: I added the code in app.js, which is the only other code normally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was Postman which didn't update the result view when json was returned. That's why it worked perfectly with a text result but not with json. Updated to the latest version from the website and now it works perfectly!